# converting a function types to generic function type with a mix of recursive usage of Template Literals

Tags: typescript

I am currently learning generics, but can't figure out the generic variables that should be used to convert this function to a generic function which should return `string literals` instead of `string`.

I have created this recursive function for creating routes:

```
interface CreateRouteParams {
  path: string;
  dependsOn?: CreateRouteParams;
}

const createRoute = ({ path, dependsOn }: CreateRouteParams): { path: string; backPath?: string } => {
  if (!dependsOn) return { path };

  const parent = createRoute(dependsOn);

  // avoid 2 sequential slashes at the beginning of path
  if (parent.path === '/') {
    return { path: `${parent.path}${path}`, backPath: `${dependsOn.path}` };
  }

  return { path: `${parent.path}/${path}`, backPath: `${dependsOn.path}` };
};
```

And I use it like this:

```
const root = {
  path: '/',
};

const auth = createRoute({
  path: 'auth',
  dependsOn: root,
});

const login = createRoute({
  path: 'login',
  dependsOn: auth,
});
```

e.g. If I hover over `login`, it shows its type as `{ path: string, backPath?: string | undefined }` at the moment. But if generic solution is implemented correctly, then it should show `{ path:` /auth/login`, backPath:` /auth` }

I know that I will need to use `recursive template literals` with a mix of `generics`, but can't figure out the exact thing. And I have posted the code without any generics applied, so that even if I am on wrong way, then it does not have any impact on the one who is trying to solve this one.

Here is the playground: [Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMJQnSAlA9gV0gAU4o4BbAZ2QG8BYAKGWQAcsALALmUrClADmAbkbMAJhBYQQYygHkQAfm7pMOAsVIVKIhgF9GjBLhC9kCDFgh5CKALzIAFDVYcANMglSZ8kMj0qluq2JGRUAJTcLmxgXDx8gkLIAEaIANYkscrx-CAC-sh2AHy0osjAME4AhF7SsgrhyBhg%20FB%200Rz%20umXGpmCuGOCF5kHWGhCOtT4N3UzIAPTzyHAAbrjAYsgATDwQAI740mDAcAA2PKdwlOwQ1FjIsSjJEAKgIILIuJUx7GUVTmxBmAAHQ-Qp2BwAcnmkMa9DmzGarXarli3AABgASGiAo6gjh6bE-PTojypBAZDgY7FTeogfGxEldMoGBhlJFtWiouJYnGkPHE%20ZEgmklLpTI8mmSOq%20BnsJl6XSKwwMCAADxYuCg-V6ZiguFw-Qc8OYP240MhbkYyrZqo1Wp1JjMcEI7GGFjUY1szjKZuQkJdsUtZVpvm4%20sNVv04Vm6s12vMTv6p1wrz8Dg9VhskB9cz9kJTaeDc1DCm4gfYUb0MZVQA)

Any suggestions for code improvement are also welcome :)

Comment: So would something like [this](https://tsplay.dev/wOlxzN) fit your needs?

Comment: Oh you beat me, I have [this version](https://tsplay.dev/WKP9yw). I'm more than happy to defer to @pink here as long as they deal with that double-slash issue.

Comment: Whoops, didn't see that at first... https://tsplay.dev/WJV75W

Comment: @pink that's a great solution. And a great follow up by jcalz too. Thank you very much for the playground links. Can you please post it as answer, so that it can help someone else in future?

Comment: @pink if you don't mind, I have a follow up question, if you can answer that,, then it would be helpful: Why do we use function overloads?

Comment: We put the signature as an overload to avoid the annoying mismatched return type errors. Since implementation signatures are not externally visible, the only signature available is the overload we defined. Try for yourself with either of the playground links and remove the overload.

Comment: yeah tried it before asking and got errors in return statements. My only concern with function overloads is that the function becomes non-type-safe.